# printing in linux

Tags: linux, unix, printing, cups

I've been a linux user for quite some time. But haven't do printing until now.
I just wanna ask how to do printing in linux?

I have researched a bit on it. I found some `$> echo "print me" > /dev/lp0`, but unfortunately, I have no `lp0` in my `/dev`.
I don't know if this is the right thing to do.

Nevertheless, please tell me of ways on how I can print from my linux box.
Here are some details:

- OS: debian linux 5.0.4
- printer: disclosed until it is necessary
- connection: usb connection

So do i need to add a printer first? From the printer manual that I read, this printer model has no linux driver.

Comment: I think this is a wrong place for such questions. You should ask on http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 2):

Traditionally, [`lpr`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lpr) is used to queue print jobs.  As various printing systems evolved, most provided an `lpr`-compatible command.

CUPS's [`lpr`](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/man-lpr.html) is (unsurprisingly) named `lpr`, so just use it to send print jobs to a CUPS server.

Comment: I checked on my linux, but found no lpr.

Comment: @Neilvert: What's your distro?  Debian packages it in `cups-bsd` (BSD commands for CUPS, separate from the `cups` package itself because it conflicts with the traditional `lpr` and older `lprng` systems), and Ubuntu inherits that.  These packages may be named `cupsys-bsd` and `cupsys` on older Debian/Ubuntu distros.

Comment: my distro is debian.

Comment: if my debian has no lpr, then what to do about it?

Comment: @Neilvert: So install `cups-bsd` (or `cupsys-bsd` if that fails).  Or if you have `cups-client` (or `cupsys-client`) installed, then you'll have the SysV-heritage [`lp`](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/man-lp.html).

Answer (score 0):

Whats the output of the commad lsusb...As far as i know you need to install the printer driver or just install cups and on the browser type http://localhost:631 and then add the printer and try printing a test page, see whther the printer you are using is listed while you add printer..(but at this point u need to show ppd file)

The PPD file type is primarily associated with 'PostScript Printer Description'. A PPD file describes fonts, paper sizes, resolution, and other capabilities for a particular Postscript printer. Printer drivers use a PPD file to understand the capabilities of a particular printer.

So just try it out and let me know how it goes !! hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Knowing what printer make and model you have is important because setting up a printer under Linux can take three paths:

1) The printer is directly supported with a named driver

2) The printer is well supported using a driver from a different make/model that works pretty well with your printer

3) You need/get best results with the software and drivers supplied by the printer manufacturer - HP is a good example here.

As others have said, you will need the CUPS printing system installed to make life easier, so have a look at the link below - and tell us a bit more about your printer.

http://wiki.debian.org/SystemPrinting